# C : conditional memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-management, while-loop, conditional-statements

How do I free up memory based on these conditions?:
If used memory is < 25% of the capacity of the system, free up 50% of unused memory.

Here is my code attempt:

[main method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbABQ.png)

[attempt at conditional memory free-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBkuA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be

```
if(rand() % 1 > 0) {
```

`rand() % 1` is always `0`

Change to:

```
if(rand() % 2 > 0) {
```

And there is a typo in:

```
while(current = !NULL) {
```

change to

```
while(current != NULL) {
```

Don't forget to reconnect `next` node to the previous one in the loop , use a temp node, something like:

```
  temp = current;
  while (current != NULL) {
    next = current->next;
    if (rand() % 2 > 0) {
      temp->next = next;
      free(current);
    } else {
      temp = current;
    }
    current = next;
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'reconnect the next node to the previous one'?

Comment: How do I do that? I'm really stuck :(

Comment: I just tested it: apparently temp becomes an unused variable!

Comment: And I'm getting a weird error: Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast. What does that mean?

Comment: It means that in `int *sizeOfUsedMemory = dl->size;` you are assigning the value of an integer to a pointer, change to `int sizeOfUsedMemory = dl->size;`, I suggest you to read a good book, linked lists are not for starters.

Comment: no, it gives me the same error after I've changed it to int sizeOfUsedMemory = dl->size;

Comment: All my code is here, I've linked some pictures as well of the main method (apart from initialisation)

Comment: No, all your code is not here, and my gcc can not compile pictures :)

Comment: Thanks for your help sir. I'll add my whole code here, give me sec :)

Comment: My whole program is up ;)

Comment: `warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
         while(current = !NULL) {`

Comment: LOL!!! I just realised I used = !NULL instead of != NULL hahahaha what a waste of time, sorry man, thanks for your help!

Comment: I found out before the edit but we posted at the same time lmao